# ZF3: Read out url parameter in PhpRenderer

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I want to upgrade from ZF2 to ZF3 right now and has the following problem with using URL parameter in my PhpRenderer.

In ZF2 I use the `HelperPluginManager` to get `Application`, then the `MvcEvent` and finally the `routeMatch`:

```
$routeMatch = $this
   ->getHelperPluginManager()
   ->getServiceLocator()
   ->get('Application')
   ->getMvcEvent()
   ->getRouteMatch();

$parameterAction = $routeMatch->getParam('action');
```

In ZF3 there is a deprecation warning with using the `getServiceLocator()` (which makes sense, because it only returns the creationContext from the `ServiceManager`). I want to find a way not trigger the warning.

Configure the `Application` as a factory-using class (using `\Zend\Mvc\Service\ApplicationFactory::class`) also not works, because:

> Zend\View\HelperPluginManager can only create instances of Zend\View\Helper\HelperInterface and/or callables.

Is there any way to get the `Application` context in my template (or better even the parameters of the URL)?

Comment: The best way is probably to get the parameters in the controller and assign those to the view. Keep your logic out of the views/templates as much as you can.

Answer (score 0):

Your question title is "ZF3: Read out url parameter in PhpRenderer" while inside your question you asked another one.

You can get this in any controller (get URL parameters in ZF3):

```
$URLparam = (string)$this->params()->fromQuery('parameter', '');
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am not in the Controller context here, I am in the View PhpRenderer. "Injecting" variables from Controller into the View context seems to be possible.

Is there a possibility to get these parameters directly in the PhpRenderer?

Answer (score 0):

For routeMatch, if you have a MvcEvent just use;

```
$event->getRouteMatch()
```

If you have container;

```
$container->getApplication()->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch();
```

If you want to access routeMatch in view there's no way except view helper like [tasmaniski/zend-current-route](https://github.com/tasmaniski/zend-current-route)